# simple html dom does not work on my dedicated server

Tags: curl, fetch, php, simple-html-dom

I hope someone from you will understand my problem and advise me a best solution.

See, I have made a data fetching script in php that works with simple html dom.php to pull data from an external website. When i was hosting my website on shared server, this script was working without any problem. but when i moved to a dedicated server i started to get the following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in /home/sitename/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 1234

I have seen this line i got this code

```
// Have php try to detect the encoding from the text given to us.
        $charset = mb_detect_encoding($this->root->plaintext . "ascii", $encoding_list = array( "UTF-8", "CP1252" ) );
        if (is_object($debugObject)) {$debugObject->debugLog(2, 'mb_detect found: ' . $charset);}
```

I do not know what is wrong. When i talked to my web host. then i do not know what he did. this error is not appearing anymore but any data is also not appearing. I mean i can not see anything in my webpage where i am using this code. you can say the webpage is not getting load when i comes to my script.

Any idea why it is not appearing ?

It is working perfectly right now in shared hosting account.
Does i need to install before making it working in a dedicated server ?

Please reply

Comment: try `echo ( function_exists( "mb_detect_encoding" ) ) ? "yes" : "no";`, if its showing "no", they have turned off `error_reporting`, so you will never see any error

Comment: @bystwn22 hi where to put this code. i mean in the script or somewhere else !!

Comment: @bystwn22 Yes you were right it is showing no .. It means the error is the same ..

Comment: @bystwn22 do you know how can i make it enable to see the error.

Comment: Read here to know how to turn on `error_reporting` http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php‎, and you must install `mbstring` to work with `mb_*` functions, read @JohnMorris answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the mbstring PHP extension.  Your previous shared server must have had it installed, but your dedicated server does not.

Perhaps your web hosting company can install it.  If not, you'll have to do it yourself.  How it is installed depends on your operating system on the server.  But if you Google "install mbstring php extension on *your OS here*", you should be able to find what you're looking for. If not, then to help any further we'll need to know the operating system and version.

Comment: On my dedicated server as i found it is Linux operating system. Actually i manage my website by cPanel..

Comment: Okay. I don't have access to cPanel, but a quick Google search gave me this: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/enable-install-mbstring-module-158165.html#post663917.

Comment: Your answer was correct. I got it, Now it is working and you know what this was my first experience with dedicated server. I fixed it. Thanks.. May god bless U.